opencv - contour to screen points
I am using opencv.js and my code is based on the intelligent scissors tutorial:
let src = cv.imread('canvasInput');
//cv.resize(src, src, new cv.Size(1024, 1024));
cv.imshow('canvasOutput', src);

let tool = new cv.segmentation_IntelligentScissorsMB();
tool.setEdgeFeatureCannyParameters(32, 100);
tool.setGradientMagnitudeMaxLimit(200);
tool.applyImage(src);

let hasMap = false;

let canvas = document.getElementById('canvasOutput');
canvas.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let startX = e.offsetX, startY = e.offsetY; console.log(startX, startY);
    if (startX < src.cols && startY < src.rows)
    {
        console.time('buildMap');
        tool.buildMap(new cv.Point(startX, startY));
        console.timeEnd('buildMap');
        hasMap = true;
    }
});
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    let x = e.offsetX, y = e.offsetY; //console.log(x, y);
    let dst = src.clone();
    if (hasMap && x >= 0 && x < src.cols && y >= 0 && y < src.rows)
    {
        let contour = new cv.Mat();
        tool.getContour(new cv.Point(x, y), contour);
        let contours = new cv.MatVector();
        contours.push_back(contour);
        let color = new cv.Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255);  // RGBA
        cv.polylines(dst, contours, false, color, 1, cv.LINE_8);
        contours.delete(); contour.delete();
    }
    cv.imshow('canvasOutput', dst);
    dst.delete();
});
canvas.addEventListener('dispose', e => {
    src.delete();
    tool.delete();
});

Instead of drawing the polylines of the contour to the canvas with the cv.polylines(dst, contours, false, color, 1, cv.LINE_8); method, I want to convert the contours into an array of screen points or canvas points (width, height). [[w0, h0], ... [wi, hi]]
When I inspect the contour variable after calling the tool.getContour(new cv.Point(x, y), contour); I see this:


Contour is a Mat with datatype CV_32SC2, representing a list of point coordinates. Single column, each row contains one coordinate, each coordinate is a pair of signed 32bit integers. I'm not familiar with the JS API, but the approach to read the individual points would be the same as reading, say, pixel values from an image (which is also an OpenCV Mat).

e.g. contour.intAt(0, 0) gets you X coordinate of first point, contour.intAt(0, 1) gets you Y coordinate of first point. And if I read the docs right, contour.intPtr(0, 0) would get you a 2-element Int32Array containing [x, y] of the first point. The first argument in all the cases is the index of the point in the contour.

@DanMašek Thank you for your help. I am getting it now!

Based on @DanMašek comment here is the solution
let contour = new cv.Mat();
tool.getContour(new cv.Point(x, y), contour);

var coords = []
for (var i=0; i<contour.matSize[0]; i++) {
  coords.push(contour.intPtr(i));
}

